# ArcGIS Server Object Extension (SOE) RestOperation configuration

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, server-object-extension

How would you accept a call to a RestOperation with string and reply back with a json array of the column names in the table holding this information?

So, if string is 'owners' then get names of col1,col4,col9,col10, if string is 'zipcode' get name of col9. etc...

New to the SOE, and excited for some guidance, thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to form a JSON response with an array of values from the SOE handler? Or do you want to know how to get the column information from a table?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Server, and what will you be developing SOE in (.NET or Java)?

Comment: I believe both. Value would be posted to SOE, returning table information (header names from sql query - if string is x then select x,y,z column names) into an array. This array will be consumed by listbox in javascript app. thanks!

Comment: version of AGS is 10.2, SOE in .NET.